# Android: How to call a function daily with AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, function, alarmmanager

I have a Tracking App which saves Timestamps and Coordinates.
Now I want to save this to a txt file every day on 23:55 o'clock.
Is it possible to open my writing function with the AlarmManager in the same Activity?
I haven't find something concrete how to call a function with the AlarmManager in the same Activity.
Can you give me a concrete example how to do this?

I have the following code:

```
...
public void onRegister() {
    locationClient.connect();

    // Set the time to 11:55:00 pm:
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    // Adjust calendar day if time of day has already occurred today:
    if (cal.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis())
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LocationLogic.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, serviceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}
...
```

But how to execute the saving function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your file-writing code to a `Service`; I recommend using an [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) because everything inside of `onHandleIntent` will be run on a background thread and the service will stop itself when finished.

```
public class LocationLogic extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    /* Services must have a no-arg constructor */
    public LocationLogic() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHangleIntent(Intent intent) {
        /* your code here */
    }
}
```

Then use AlarmManager to start up your service every day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that extends the BroadcastReceiver that will be called when the service runs.

You can find more information here: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/android-alarm-manager_31.html